# Qt drag and drop animation

Tags: qt

I have two QTreeViews side by side and I want to implement dragging one item from one table into the other table. What I would like to do however is that when the item to be dropped reaches the destination table, that the two rows sort of "make space for it" and separate to really show the user exactly where the item would be dropped. Could someone point me in the right direction as to how to do this as I have no idea really where to start.
Thanks,
Stephen

Answer (score 0):

http://doc.trolltech.com/latest/dnd.html should lead you to pretty much anything you want to do re drag and drop.

As for your specific goal, you need to implement QWidget::dragMoveEvent(QDragMoveEvent* event), which will get called every time the mouse moves within the destination tree while dragging an item.  Then get the position of the cursor with QDragMoveEvent::pos().  After that, while in dragMoveEvent, use QTreeView::indexAt(pos()) to get the item under the mouse.  Now, I don't know how to get the items to separate in a smooth animated way, which would be ideal.  But what you can do is (temporarily) add a blank item to the list, which will have the almost identical effect.  Then implement QWidget::dropEvent() to handle the drop event, and when this happens delete the blank item and insert the dragged item in the location where it was.